# Miniconda hangs on "conda info"

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

On Fedora: When I run `conda info` in a terminal the command just completely hangs and is uninterruptible. The only way to get rid of it is to kill it via process manager. All the other `conda` commands work, e.g. `conda env list` properly lists all environments. Why is `conda info` hanging? Is there any way to debug what's causing this?

I need to find out, because VS Code's python plugin is dependent on that and as a consequence it also hangs.

EDIT: `conda --debug info` also hangs

Comment: Possibly related to this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9306.  What version of conda are you using?

Comment: I am using conda version 4.8.1